# C# usercontrol show

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created one user control with some things on it, and I need to know if it's possible in my `form1` click in one `button` and that `button` open my `usercontrol` but not inside the `form1`.
I want to see the `usercontrol` separated from the `form1`, so if the user want to close the `usercontrol` he will close it and can keep the `from1`, or if the user want's to minimize the `form1` and keep the `usercontrol` in the screen.

i have tested with this

```
                        UC lauchUC = new UC(person);
                        lauchUC.Show();
```

but that don't show nothing, and also tested with this:

```
                        UC lauchUC = new UC(person);
                        this.Controls.Add(lauchUC);
```

but it appears in the form

can someone help me or telling me if it's possible show it separated from the form?

Comment: You could pass an instance of your `UserControl` to the constructor of the `Form`. In this constructor, you can add it to it's `Controls`. Just create a new `Form` and alter it's constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass an instance of your `UserControl` to the constructor of the `Form`. In this constructor, you can add it to it's Controls. Just create a new `Form` and alter it's constructor.

*The (container) Form:*

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1(UserControl control)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Controls.Add(control);
    }
}
```

---

*How to open it.*

```
public void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myControl = new MyUserControl();
    var form = new Form1(myControl);
    form.Show();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank You! was looking for this for a while

Comment: How do we dispose usercontrol form?

Answer (score 1):

You can Place it in a Window and call Window.ShowDialog.

```
 private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Window window = new Window 
        {
            Title = "My User Control Dialog",
            Content = new UC(person)
        };

        window.ShowDialog();
    }
```